# Graph : Vertex labeling

Tags: graph-theory

i have 2 graphs for a molecule with different vertex labels. How can I make the vertex labels of the second graph the same as the first graph?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoNmj.png)

Comment: Copy the first graph, replacing the second

Answer (score 0):

1. Construct the SMILES ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system ) representation of each graph. The two SMILES strings should be identical
2. Attach the labels of the 1st graph to the locations in its SMILES representation.  Do the same for the second. Now the labels of graph 1 will be attached to the same locations in the SMILES representation of the second graph
3. Replace the labels in one graph with the label attached to the same location in the other graph

---

You asked ( in a comment ) "How can I add attach the labels for the SMILES"

The wikipedia article describes how to convert a graph into a SMILES representation.

Without more information, such as your graph format, it is extremely hard to be more specific.

Let me try.  Assuming that your graph format is something like this:

```
raven::graph::cGraph ingraph;
ingraph.add( "C1","H1");
ingraph.add( "C1","H2");
ingraph.add( "C1","H3");
ingraph.add( "C1","C2");
ingraph.add( "C2","H4");
ingraph.add( "C2","H5");
ingraph.add( "C2","O1");
ingraph.add( "C1","H6");
```

Then a first draft of the code to attach graph labels to locations in the SMILES string would be like this:

```
void cChemGraph::graphtoSMILES(const raven::graph::cGraph &g)
{
    std::string SMILES;                 // the SMILES representation of the chemical graph
    std::vector<std::string> vLabel;    // the label locations

    // remove bonds to Hydrogen
    raven::graph::cGraph noH = g;
    for (auto &bond : noH.edgeList())
    {
        if (noH.userName(bond.first)[0] == 'H' || noH.userName(bond.second)[0] == 'H')
            noH.remove(bond.first, bond.second);
    }

    // depth first search of graph
    dfs(noH, 0,
        [&](int v)
        {
            // get the atom label
            auto label = noH.userName(v);

            switch (label[0])
            {
            case 'C':
            case 'O':
            case 'N':
                vLabel.push_back(label);
                SMILES += label[0];
                break;
            default:
                vLabel.push_back("-");
                break;
            }
            return true;
        });

    std::cout << "SMILES: " << SMILES << "\n";
    std::cout << "\nlabel locations in SMILES string:\n";
    for (int k = 0; k < vLabel.size(); k++)
        std::cout << k << "\t" << vLabel[k] << "\n";
}
```

The output is

```
SMILES: CCO

label locations in SMILES string:
0       C1
1       C2
2       O1
```

For cyclohexane:

```
SMILES: C1CCCCC1

label locations in SMILES string:
0       C1
1       -
2       C6
3       C5
4       C4
5       C3
6       C2
7       -
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How can I add attach the labels for the SMILES?

Comment: To answer that, you will need to share the format of your input.  "i have 2 graphs"  - so, please post the format of the files that store these graphs.

Comment: I have provided some code for you, as best as I can without mode details from you.

Comment: I have not heard from you in a couple of days.  Are you still interested in this?  I have added handling of cycles - see sample output for cyclohexane.

Comment: I work with Wolfarm Mathematica and unfortunately I cannot use your code. However, I tried to rewrite the equivalent code in Mathematica, but I did not succeed

Comment: In fact, I have two pdb files of one molecule in which the names of the atoms are different. To calculate RMSD The atom names must be the same. I am looking for a way to make the names of the atoms in the second file the same as the names of the same atoms in the first file.